# Spring boot 2 Transaction managers and 2 @Transactional

Tags: spring, spring-boot, transactions

I have Spring boot with two databases (first and second).
I have this working configuration:

```
@Bean
public DataSourceTransactionManager firstDbTransactionManager(@Qualifier ("primaryDataSource") DataSource datasource) {
    return new DataSourceTransactionManager(datasource);
}

@Bean
public DataSourceTransactionManager secondDbTransactionManager(@Qualifier("secondaryDataSource") DataSource datasource) {
    return new DataSourceTransactionManager(datasource);
}
```

And i have method that need to be @Transactional for both db.
That i doing all the time, and it works fine:

```
@Autowired
private SubscriptionFeeService thisBeanSelfProxy;

@Transactional("firstDbTransactionManager")
public void withdrawalOfMonthlyFee(Project project) throws Exception {
    thisBeanSelfProxy.intermediateMethod(project);
}

@Transactional("secondDbTransactionManager")
public void intermediateMethod(Project project) throws Exception {
    thisBeanSelfProxy.withdrawalOfMonthlyFeeInner(project);
}

public void withdrawalOfMonthlyFeeInner(Project project) throws Exception {
    firstDbRepository.update(project);
    secondDbRepostory.addNewOperationToProjectTable(project.generateOperations());
    throw new RuntimeException(); //i want rollback both db
}
```

i am creating intermediateMethod just for @Transactional annotation because it does not support @Transactional({"firstDbTransactionManager", "secondDbTransactionManager"}). How to open both transaction by one annotation?

Comment: You probably actually want a single global transaction spanning the two datasources. You need a JTA transaction manager for that (provided by a Java EE app server or Atomikos, for example).